# RandomForestClassifier: poor recall after GridSearchCV

Tags: python, random-forest, grid-search

I start developing a model using RandomForestClasifier. I used GridSearchCV with scroing='recall' to find the best parameters to fit the model.

I know that at this moment the model will not performing well. But I am confused why it became worse using the GridSearch parameters compared to baseline model. I also tried RandomzizedSearchCV with the same behaviour.

```
=== Base Model ===
=== Confusion Matrix ===
[[11181   305]
 [ 2289   139]]

=== Random Model ===
=== Confusion Matrix ===
[[11485     1]
 [ 2426     2]]
```

I was not expecting that my true positive turns to 0 after scoring for recall.

```
n_estimators = [int(x) for x in np.linspace(start = 100, stop = 1000, num = 10)]
max_features = ['auto', 'sqrt']
max_depth = [int(x) for x in np.linspace(10, 20, num = 5)]
max_depth.append(None)
min_samples_split = [2, 5, 10]
min_samples_leaf = [int(x) for x in np.linspace(10, 100, num = 4)]
bootstrap = [True, False]
random_grid = {'n_estimators': n_estimators,
               'max_features': max_features,
               'max_depth': max_depth,
               'min_samples_split': min_samples_split,
               'min_samples_leaf': min_samples_leaf,
               #'bootstrap': bootstrap               }

rfo_random = GridSearchCV(RandomForestClassifier(), random_grid,scoring='recall',n_jobs = -1,verbose=5)
```

rfo_random.best_params_ tells me:

```
Out[144]: 
{'max_depth': 17,
 'max_features': 'sqrt',
 'min_samples_leaf': 10,
 'min_samples_split': 5,
 'n_estimators': 100}
```

Is there anything wrong with my code? I hope someone could help me.

Happy Weekend

Christoph

Comment: Did you have a look at the individual true positive rates over the grid (i.e. the distribution)? Or did you compute a ROC curve for comparison?

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that since your dataset is very inbalanced towards the `zero` class, maximizing the recall puts all the predictions there since it has a lot more samples. You can see the `zero` class recall got better: 11485 Random Model vs 11181 Base Model.

I think what you really want is to maximize is the recall of the `one` class: `recall(averaging='binary', pos_label=1)`.

Or in your code:

`rfo_random = GridSearchCV(RandomForestClassifier(), random_grid, scoring='recall_binary', n_jobs = -1, verbose=5)`

You can find more info in the [scikit-learn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.recall_score.html)

Comment: Thanks so far. I was struggeling with the code on Friday. The scorer seems to work now. "scorer = make_scorer(recall_score,average='binary', pos_label=1)"  I start with RandomizedSearch but results are still bad.

Comment: Try `F1` or `ROC_AUC`